# Is there a way to import * (all) from a module by string?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a dynamically defined settings object where typically you would use the format

**base_settings.py**:

```py
MY_VAR = 1
```

**my_settings.py**:

```py
from base_settings import *
assert MY_VAR == 1
```

however in this case I would like `base_settings` to be a string that defines the path to different setting modules. For instance, I may have the additional base settings files:

**base_settings1.py**:

```py
MY_VAR = 1
```

**base_settings2.py**:

```py
MY_VAR = 2
```

**my_settings.py**:

```py
import os
base_settings = os.environment['SETTINGS_MODULE']  # This is "base_settings2" for the example
from magic(base_settings) import *
assert MY_VAR == 2
```

I'm aware that you can import with `importlib.import_module(path)` however this returns the imported code into a specific variable rather than "exploded" into the importing file with the original variable names.

Comment: is https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__ what you are after?

Comment: @malmiteria I don't believe so, as I want the imported variables to be available immediately as local variables on the importing script, I'll update my question to clarify.

Comment: Why is your settings module dynamically named? Why can't you use a JSON file instead for example?

Comment: @cricket_007 I believe because loading by JSON would suffer the same problem in that the imported variables would not be created as local-level variables.

Comment: They would be if you added them to `locals()` dictionary...

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks! The first answer suggests the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `locals` namespace, although it really not reccomended:

```
mod_name = os.environment['SETTINGS_MODULE']
locals().update({
    k: v for k, v in importlib.import_module(mod_name).__dict__.items() 
    if not k.startswith('_')
})
```

This will add to you local (module) variables the one found in your settings module.

However, it's higly reccomended to keep your confing in a closed object.

Comment: Thanks! This might be what I'm looking for. However why is it highly recommended to keep my config in a closed object? Simply to avoid the complexity of this question/answer or is there other potential problems or best practice breaches?

Comment: In general, modifying locals() is considered bad practice because that way we are interfering in the python's interpreter domain. Instead having a "config" variable containing all the per-enviroment variables will let you separate the intepreters domain and the "enviroment" domain. Also, you can access your config from every module in your app you by importing it. Have a look at the configparser module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

Comment: I guess I'm not being completely transparent in that I'm building a django settings file, which generally expects all the variables to be set locally, so I don't have the luxury of fully designing the settings module specification myself.

Comment: So, if you are following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/, I gues you just can write base_settings1.py and base_settings2.py, and set the enviroment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to "base_settings2" or "base_settings2" and then you can import you settings from everywhere using "from django.conf import settings"

Comment: thanks, I'm aware of that basic usage. However our codebase runs multiple apps, across multiple environments (dev/staging/UAT/production) for multiple clients with different feature sets, so short of having a separate file for every permutation, we've gone for a cascading approach of multiple levels of importing. Being able to intentionally inject values into `locals()` however could open some new possibilities though, thanks!